# Using the SearchBox in Office UI Fabric React CommandBar

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm trying to work out how to use the built in search box component on the CommandBar within Office UI Fabric React

The documentation at http://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/commandbar doesn't seem to cover it.

Specifically I'd like to know how to get the search term entered and to execute a search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked the source: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/CommandBar/CommandBar.tsx

The searchbox is implemented as a simple input element:

```
if (isSearchBoxVisible) {
  searchBox = (
    <div className={ css('ms-CommandBarSearch', styles.search) } ref='searchSurface'>
      <input className={ css('ms-CommandBarSearch-input', styles.searchInput) } type='text' placeholder={ searchPlaceholderText } />
      <div className={ css(
        'ms-CommandBarSearch-iconWrapper ms-CommandBarSearch-iconSearchWrapper',
        styles.searchIconWrapper, styles.searchIconSearchWrapper) }>
        <i className={ css('ms-Icon ms-Icon--Search') }></i>
      </div>
      <div className={ css(
        'ms-CommandBarSearch-iconWrapper ms-CommandBarSearch-iconClearWrapper ms-font-s',
        styles.searchIconWrapper,
        styles.searchIconClearWrapper
      ) }>
        <i className={ css('ms-Icon ms-Icon--Cancel') }></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It can be accessed with the refs property:

```
  public refs: {
    [key: string]: React.ReactInstance;
    commandSurface: HTMLElement;
    farCommandSurface: HTMLElement;
    commandBarRegion: HTMLElement;
    searchSurface: HTMLElement;
    focusZone: FocusZone;
  };
```

Now you could try to use the standard properties and events of an input element. (I haven't tried.)

Comment: is there a way to add Search to this CommandBar? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar